# Stripe Subscriptions: take payment immediately for future subscriptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create Stripe Subscription for future dates but with immediate payment charge.

I found [Scheduled Subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules) but it seems like charges for such subscriptions will be triggered at `start_date`

```
Stripe::SubscriptionSchedule.create({
  customer: 'cus_...',
  start_date: 1667378929,
  end_behavior: 'release',
  phases: [
    {
      items: [{ price: 'plan', quantity: 1 }],
      proration_behavior: 'always_invoice'
    },
  ],
})
```

Creating of scheduled subscription from existing subscription had no effect as well - subscription cannot be transformed from "basic" type to scheduled with future date

```
Stripe::SubscriptionSchedule.create({
  from_subscription: 'sub_...',
})
```

Comment: If that's the case why not create a separate plan for let's say `annual` plan or a plan for `6 months`?

Comment: Just a raw idea: you could _probably_ use subscription phases for that with some artificial "idle" phase that starts immediately (and paid immediately) followed by the phase that represent the actual subscription terms (and is provided for free). But I would think twice really: taking money before the subscription started can lead to the increased number of chargebacks and it potentially can have a very serious consequences for the merchant (read about "High risk merchant lists")

Answer (score 0):

If you want the subscription to start in the future then there's no built in way to make the customer pay immediately. But there are possible workarounds, for example:

Ask for the customer to pay upfront and save their payment method, then once the payment is successful create a subscription schedule to start the subscription in the future. You probably want to add a free trial at the beginning of the subscription schedule so that the customer doesn't end up paying twice.

Or create the subscription right away, with a free trial and and an invoice item (for the amount you want to charge upfront). Then track on your end when the subscription should actually give the user access to your service.